# plot many UK postcodes in R

Tags: r

I have postcodes each with some summary statistic S1. Using code like this:

```
datamap <- read.table("SomeGeocodedPostcodes.txt",
                   header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

datamap_mat <- cbind(datamap$Longitude,datamap$Latitude)
row.names(datamap_mat) <- 1:nrow(datamap_mat)
AACRS <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")

UK_Map <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(datamap_mat, datamap, proj4string = AACRS, match.ID = TRUE) 

m <- plotGoogleMaps(UK_Map , filename='MAP_UK1.html')
```

works great for a small number of postcodes. Which options do I have in R to get this to work for a large-ish number of postcodes (about 30k)? Maybe it can be downcast to out postcodes and I can draw a heatmap based on polygons of out postcodes?